# How do I create collapsible sections in the gitlab output from inside python script?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci

According to the docs it should be simple:

```
@contextmanager
def gitlab_section(name, header):
    print(f'\033[0Ksection_start:{int(time.time())}:{name}[collapsed=true]\r\033[0K{header}')
    yield
    print(f'\033[0Ksection_end:{int(time.time())}:{name}:\r\033[0K')
```

however, using it like this:

```
with gitlab_section('first', 'First'):
    print('first section')

print("After first section")

with gitlab_section('second', 'Second'):
    print('second section')
```

makes the "After.." line fold into the first section.

I've made it work with a horrible hack that starts a dummy section after each `section_end`:

```
def unique():
    return int(random.random() * 1000000000)

@contextmanager
def gitlab_section(name, header):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sectionid = unique()    # in case someone uses the same name twice...
    print(f'\033[0Ksection_start:{int(time.time())}:{name}_{sectionid}[collapsed=true]\r\033[0K{header}')
    yield
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(f'\nsection_end:{int(time.time())}:{name}_{sectionid}:\r\033[0K')
    # start a dummy section without a header
    print(f'\033[0Ksection_start:{int(time.time())}:dummy_{unique()}\r\033[0K')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

the `\e[0K` prefix doesn't seem to be needed on `section_end` (and the gitlab generated output does not use it).

While this works, it seems horribly hacky. I've read the docs, thoroughly, but perhaps I missed something in the first example..?

What about nested collapsible sections, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small error in your section end marker:

```py
    print(f'\033[0Ksection_end:{int(time.time())}:{name}:\r\033[0K')
```

Should be:

```py
    print(f'\033[0Ksection_end:{int(time.time())}:{name}\r\033[0K')
```

Note you have an extra `:` and `:` is not a legal character within a section name, so the regex parser is missing your section end, which is why the line afterwards is being grouped into the first section.

---

Regarding nested collapsed sections: [sections are supposed to be able to be nested infinitely](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/335297). This was [originally implemented behind the feature flag `infinitely_collapsible_sections`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/65496). The feature flag has since been removed some time in v15, however the feature is still not currently working at the time of writing (v16.4), due to [bugs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29766) that have yet to be fixed.

By the current implementation detail, a new section will imply the end of the previous section. See [this MR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/4272) for more information. So, it would seem at this time, you cannot nest sections (or at least they won't show up as nested in the UI).